# Probability of sample space occurrence when the subset has occurred

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I came across a statement while reading *Introduction To Probability* from "***Probability and Statistics*** by *Morris Degroot and Mark Schervis*, 4th Edition", mentioned in section 1.4 page 7

Link of the book is mentioned below :-

[Book Link](https://bio5495.wustl.edu/Probability/Readings/DeGroot4thEdition.pdf)

> Definition 1.4.2 - For Events, to say that $A\subset B$ means that if A occurs then so does B.

**Example**

let' say A contains following events {took a glass from cupboard, filled glass with water, drank water from the glass}. Now A is contained in B as it is a subset of B. Hence, B may have either same no. of events as A or some extra events more than A. Let's consider the later scenario, it has certain extra events, so we may say B is {took a glass from cupboard, filled glass with water, drank water from the glass, watched TV, went to studies and slept}.

**Question**

According to above definition if B has occurred and is a subset of A, then A has occurred but we see the extra events in B besides the ones those are in A hasn't happened yet. So, how can we say that B has occurred ?

Anyone can give me a proper intuition for the above definition with proper examples ? Besides that am I going wrong through my example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say $A \subset B$. This means that $A \cap B = A$, then by definition of conditional probability (probability of $B$ happening given $A$ has happened):
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}=1$$
Now for a more tangible example, consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Let's consider the set $A=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)>a\}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and the set $B=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) > b\}$ for some $b < a$. We have that $A \subset B$. If $X$ happens to be greater than $a$, it is also greater than $b$.

Comment: I got the proof which you did using conditional probability but didn't understand the tangible one, so if you can cite a real life example that would suffice. Thanx

Comment: @noob_python consider a game with a fair coin and the only two events $\omega_H$ and $\omega_T$. If you get heads you win $1$, $0$ otherwise. Consider $A=\{X>0.6\}=\{\omega_H\}$ and $B=\{X>-0.1\}=\{\omega_H,\omega_T\}$. We have that $A \subset B$. Indeed, if we win more than $0.6$, we also win more than $-0.1$, but not viceversa (if we win $0$ we don't win more than $0.6$)

Comment: Yes, pretty much clear thank you @Snoop

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt says that $A$ is a subset of $B$, not that $B$ is a subset of $A$. In other words, every outcome in $A$ is also in $B$, but $B$ may contain additional outcomes.

Suppose $B$ is the event that someone's birthday is in January, and $A$ is the event that their birthday is more specifically January 1st. If their birthday is in fact January 1 then of course they were born in January (if $A$ occurred then $B$ must have occurred as well). But if all you know is that someone was born in January, you don't know that they were specifically born on January 1. So $A \subset B$ but $B$ is not a subset of $A$.

In this setup, if you know $A$ occurred then $B$ necessarily occurred as well.

Generally, an event can contain many individual outcomes and we say the event occurred if **at least** 1 of those outcomes occurred. In the excerpt above, suppose that $A$ happened. Then at least one of those activities in $A$ took place. Since each of those activities are also in $B$, then it must be that $B$ also occurred, since one of $B$'s activities also took place -- just not necessarily all of them.

Comment: it seems more clear intuitively now thanx